# RSpec: New User view test failing, when it should be passing

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I have the this test:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'support/factory_girl'

RSpec.describe 'users/new', type: :view do
    before(:each) do
        assign(:user, create(:user))
    end

    it 'renders new user form' do
        render
        assert_select 'form[action=?][method=?]', users_path, 'post'
    end
end
```

And this page, the form is in the second line of this image:

[image: HtmlCode inspection]

This test fails saying that there were no forms found.

```
rspec spec/views/users/new.html.erb_spec.rb

users/new
  renders new user form (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) users/new renders new user form
     Failure/Error: assert_select 'form[action=?][method=?]', users_path, 'post'

     Minitest::Assertion:
       Expected at least 1 element matching "form[action="/users"][method="post"]", found 0..
       Expected 0 to be >= 1.
     # /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@gym-app/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/assertions.rb:139:in `assert'
     # /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@gym-app/gems/minitest-5.10.3/lib/minitest/assertions.rb:270:in `assert_operator'
     # /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@gym-app/gems/rails-dom-testing-2.0.3/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:277:in `assert_size_match!'
     # /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@gym-app/gems/rails-dom-testing-2.0.3/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:172:in `block in assert_select'
     # /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@gym-app/gems/rails-dom-testing-2.0.3/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:171:in `tap'
     # /home/ramses/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@gym-app/gems/rails-dom-testing-2.0.3/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:171:in `assert_select'
     # ./spec/views/users/new.html.erb_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.24509 seconds (files took 2.93 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/views/users/new.html.erb_spec.rb:9 # users/new renders new user form
```

What must I change in the test to make it pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the test is describing a `new` action, but in the `before(:each)` block, A user is being created, thus triggering a `edit` action.

So the problem was on the test itself, not in the view

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'support/factory_girl'

RSpec.describe 'users/new', type: :view do
    before(:each) do
        #use build instead of create, to pass a non-saved user
        assign(:user, build(:user))
    end

    it 'renders new user form' do
        render
        # you can use byebug to inspect variables.
        # byebug
        # I figured this out by inspecting the contents of the rendered var
        #inside byebug, use var to show all variables in context
        assert_select 'form[action=?][method=?]', users_path, 'post'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's problem rendering the view (maybe you didn't set up a var, and getting an error?)

put something like this:

```
it 'renders new user form' do
    render
    puts subject
    assert_select 'form[action=?][method=?]', users_path, 'post'
end
```

And inspect what is there.

Instead of `puts subject` you can set up a breakpoint there, and inspect the contents of the `subject` there, or save them in `html` file and open in your browser for inspection.

Comment: I was able to figure it out with your advice; see my answer for the solution. I used `byebug` instead of `puts subject` and inpected the `rendered` variable